# SQLite Manager Eclipse Plugin Stopped Reading Database

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, eclipse-plugin

I've been using the Questoid SQLite Manager plugin for Eclipse for over a month and it's worked fine. I just performed my first database upgrade (version 1 to version 2) and it seems to have gone fine. I added one column in each table.

Everything looks perfect in the Firefox plugin, but in Eclipse the "Browse Data" tab doesn't work. "Data Structure" correctly sows the names and schema of my tables and "Browse Data" shows the columns, but no actual data, as if the db is empty, which it isn't. Any idea what happened?

Comment: I wanted to use the Questoid SQLite Manager plugin for Eclipse for the first time. But I have a equal error and don't see the Browse Data Tab